# SQL Server Large Nested Case within 1 case

Tags: sql-server-2008, nested, case-when

I have a very large nested case that I want to place within another case - so when I do, I keep getting ')' error.  When removing the first case, the query works. Please help. Thank you.

```
Case when
    ( Case when c1 = c2 then c1 else
         case when c1 <> c2 and c1 = c3 then c1 else
              case when c1 <> c2 and c2 = c3 then c2 else
                  case when c1 <> c2 and c2 <> c3 and c3 <> c1 then c1 end
                     end 
               end 
          end ) is null then '_0' else '-true' end as Final_cc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CASE WHEN
        (Case  
              when c1 = c2                                  then c1 
              when c1 <> c2 and c1 = c3                     then c1 
              when c1 <> c2 and and c1 <> c3 and c2 = c3    then c2 
              when c1 <> c2 and c2 <> c3 and c3 <> c1       then c1 
        END)  is null 
      then '_0' 
        else '-true'  end as Final_cc
```